# Count consecutive occurrences in sql and/or pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, gaps-and-islands

I would like to check how many consecutive absences each student has had.  I have a table called class_absenses which has the following fields:

id, student_id, present (0 for absent, 1 for present), date

I would like to return a list of students_id and how many consecutive absences they have had from today to some historical day in the past (say t-30).

If this can be done in sql then great!  otherwise I am loading this into a pandas dataframe and am open to pivoting / grouping to get this done.

Thank you!

Sample Input

```
id      student_id      present      date
0       1               0            4-28-2023
1       1               0            4-27-2023
2       1               1            4-26-2023
3       2               0            4-28-2023
4       2               1            4-27-2023
5       2               0            4-26-2023
6       3               1            4-28-2023
7       3               0            4-27-2023
8       3               0            4-26-2023
```

Output

```
student_id     ConsecutiveAbsense
1              2
2              1
3              0
```

Comment: Student 3 has 2 consecutive absences.

Comment: What if you have several stretches of absence?

Comment: This is pretty easy in Python by iterating the rows, tracking the numbers in dictionaries.  What have you tried?

Comment: We only care about the consecutive absences starting at the most recent date.. therefore student 3 has 0 absences since they were most recently present

Comment: *If this can be done in sql then great!*- which database are you running: mysql, postgresql, sql-server…? Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dates are already sorted, use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate):

```py
out = (
 df.groupby('student_id')['present']
   .agg(lambda s: s.eq(0).cummin().sum())
)
```

Output:

```
student_id
1    2
2    1
3    0
Name: present, dtype: int64
```

As DataFrame:

```py
out = (
 df.groupby('student_id', as_index=False)
   .agg(ConsecutiveAbsense=('present', lambda s: s.eq(0).cummin().sum()))
)
```

Output:

```
   student_id  ConsecutiveAbsense
0           1                   2
1           2                   1
2           3                   0
```

Answer (score 0):

> If this can be done in sql then great!

In SQL, this is a gaps and islands problem. You want the length of the latest absence streak of each student (ie the latest island).

Here is one approach:

```
select *
from (
    select student_id, 
        count(*) - 1 streak_length,
        row_number() over(partition by student_id order by grp) rn
    from (
        select a.*,
            sum(presence) over(partition by student_id order by date desc) grp
        from class_absences a
    ) a
    group by student_id, grp
    having count(*) > 1
) a
where rn = 1
```

The most inner subquery defines islands, using a window sum that increments for each day of presence (`grp`). The next level aggregates islands that contains absences (ie more than one record), using `group by` and `having`, and enumerates them for each student (`row_number`) - the outer subquery filters on the latest streak per student.

You did not tag your RDBMS. This is standard SQL, that most database should support. On the other hand, some databases have extensions that would make the query neater.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the conditional max window function to find the last date when a student was present, then use that date to filter out the previous rows:

```
select student_id, count(*)- case when max(present) = 0 then 0 else 1 end ConsecutiveAbsense -- or simply count(*)-max(present)
from
  (
   select *,
    max(case when present=1 then date_ else '1900-01-01' end) over (partition by student_id) last_present_date
   from tbl_name
  ) T
where date_ >= last_present_date
group by student_id
order by student_id
```

`where date_ >= last_present_date` will include the last date where a student was present so we use `count(*)-case...` to exclude that row, this is just to include students with a 0 count. When all present values are 0s no need to exclude that row so a case expression is used to handle that.

The output for your input data:

```
student_id  consecutiveabsense
1           2
2           1
3           0
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YMmJrr9m)